# AngularJs - Use External controller.js

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Just started with Angular and trying to make this work.

I would like to display the name in the `<p></p>`, but it shows {{ name }}.

**ASPX:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Assets/Vendor/angularjs-v1.2.28.js"></script> 
    <script src="App/app.js"></script>  
    <script src="App/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp','myCtrl');
```

**controllers.js:**

```
var controller = {};

controller.myCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "abcd";
}
```

**EDIT:** I have changed the order of loading the script files and updated this query.
This is the error I see in console -  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Did you press F12 (open developer console) to see what is going wrong? You're probably getting `'app' is not defined`. My guess would be to invert the scripts `controller.js`and `app.js`.

Comment: Like @hightmastdon says.  Youre including the `app` and `controller` scripts in the wrong order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things here:

1 - `myCtrl` is not a dependent module.  So, you don't need it when defining the `myApp` module:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

2 - Order of scripts, as described by @Highmastdon.

3 - When defining the controller, you can use the `myApp` module:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'abcd';
});
```

Comment: You could add the `['$scope', function($scope){}]` in order to work with minification

Comment: I guess step3 should go in app.js.right? What if i want to put it in controllers.js. How would it be then?

Comment: @Qwerty No, the `app` variable will be added to the global scope. So, it should be accessible as long as the `controller.js` file is loaded after `app.js`.

Comment: @Qwerty no, that can be in `controllers.js`. As the page gets all scripts, they are available for use in one environment. Therefore when you load `controllers.js` after `app.js`, your app is already defined.

Comment: I would not recommend this, because it creates a habit of putting everything in the same file, which is not conform the Single responsibility principle. In my opinion this also applies to files and their contents.

Comment: @Highmastdon what are you referring to?  The `angular.module('myApp').controller(...` declaration?  This can be split just as easily.  And doesn't incur the extra global variable.  Which is better, right?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes that's what I meant. How would u add a controller in a separate file using this? You need the global variable somehow, right?

Comment: @Highmastdon No, `angular` *is* the global.  It stores the modules you have declared.  So, you can split exactly the same.  This is actually preferred, because having an extra global `app` variable is not needed and can have conflicts with other global variables (depending on the name).

Answer (score 4):

You've not correctly put the order of the scripts. Rather put `app.js` in front of `controller.js`. Now you're getting the error: `var app is not defined`.

[Addition]
Furthermore, you're trying to inject `myCtrl` which is no object. So changing `var controller` to `var myCtrl` would probably work.

Better would be to use something as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "abcd";
}]);
```